# Laravel service providers defered loading

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, deferred

I've a service provider registering authorization gates read from the database, like...

```
class PermissionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  // ...

  public function boot()
  {
    Permission::get()->map(function($permission) {
      Gate::define($permission->slug, function($user) use ($permission) {
        return $user->hasPermission($permission);
      });
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

And I've registered it in `config/app.php`

```
return [

  // ...

  $providers = [
    // ...
    App\Providers\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
  ],

];
```

**Issue:**

Tests would not run because this service provider was being called before the database connect was setup.

**Solution:**

**`Defer`** loading the service provider by setting the defer property to true.

```
class PermissionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  // ...

  protected $defer = true;

  public function boot()
  {
    Permission::get()->map(function($permission) {
      Gate::define($permission->slug, function($user) use ($permission) {
        return $user->hasPermission($permission);
      });
    });
  }

  public function provides()
  {
    // Not sure of what to do with this yet...
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

**New Issue:**

The service provider never get called at all.

**Question:**

How can I defer loading the service provider until am sure the database is setup and is accessible?

Comment: The service provider is only invoked if a binding container within the `provides()` array is called. Because you’re not actually binding anything to the container, your service provider won’t get called.

Comment: @MartinBean I could use some direction on how to go about this if you don't mind

Comment: Is it defined after the DatabaseServiceProvider in your config/app.php?

Comment: Yes, I put it at the bottom of the providers array in config.php

Comment: Why don't you use AuthServiceProvider for this?

Comment: Has same behavior. Actually, if I do an database transaction in a service provider - it fails.